# Alpine.JS is not recognizing my function used in select menu

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-jetstream

I have a problem for which I have not been able to find a solution. I have a selection menu `<select>` which executes a function each time an option is selected, which in turn assigns the value of the selected option to a variable; this, in order to dynamically display a form according to the option.

*I am developing in laravel 10, jetstream and livewire.*

```html
<x-select x-on:click="getTypes();" name="types" id="types" class="w-full" @change="showEventType = $event.target.value;" x-model="showEventType" x-data="{types: null,
getTypes() { fetch('/api/v1/event-types', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' }),
   mode: 'no-cors'
})
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((json) => this.types = json);
}}">
   <x-slot name="options">
       <option selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
       <template x-for="type in types?.data" :key="type.id">
           <option :value="type.id" x-text="type.attributes.name"></option>
       </template>
   </x-slot>
</x-select>
```

In this fragment the option value is obtained and assigned:

`@change="showEventType = $event.target.value;"`

And of course the parent element has the property `x-data`

```html
<x-dialog-modal wire:model="confirmingCreateEvent" x-data="{showEventType: ''}">
```

When I select X option, the console displays a warning saying that the function is not defined.

I do not understand what is going on, if there is some kind of "encapsulation" and if so, how to avoid it?

Any help is welcome and I will always be grateful.

Entire code here: https://pastebin.com/zkjwYqS4

This code must assign a value to a variable, which can be accessed anywhere in the modal and in such a way that it is possible to display a form according to the selected option.